# What is the difference between ape and monkey?

Tags: word-choice

To be more specific, what's the point of joke in first episode in 8th season of Doctor Who:

> "People are **apes**, men are **monkeys**."

As I can understand, 'ape' is more scientific term, and monkey is more casual and more vulgar. Am I right?

Comment: Apes & monkeys are completely different 'families' of animal. Humans are actually apes, not monkeys. The 'joke' is that monkeys are of a lower order than apes & therefore, men are a lower order than women. See http://animals.howstuffworks.com/mammals/monkeys-vs-apes.htm for a reasonably simple explanation of the differences

Comment: @Tetsujin You should write that up as an answer. It's the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a clear distinction between apes and monkeys (but not in all languages).

- **[Apes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ape)**
  are (simplified) the tailless relatives of us humans, a group containing gibbons, orangutans, gorillas and chimpanzees.
- **[Monkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey)**
  are (even more simplified) "the other ones", often with long tails. Examples are mandrills, marmosets or macaques.

In *daily speak*, often "monkey" is used for apes, too, although technically not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Both terms can be used as terms of derision. You might hear in a 1940s American movie a phrase like "Get outta here, you big ape!" There it is a synonym for "oaf". When Ren calls Stimpy a "[sick little monkey](http://youtube.com/watch?v=Nf521w1VoGU)", it implies that Stimpy engages in some kind of perverted behavior.  –