# ellipsis after "although"

Tags: ellipsis, subordinate-clauses

[infopop.cc](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/adjective-as-though):
**(1a)** *Although poor, he is quite happy*. — correct
**(1b)** *Although **he is** poor, he is quite happy*. — correct
My variant:
**(1c)** *Although **is** poor, he is quite happy*. — I don't know if it's correct

The subject of the main clause is "*he*".
The subject of the although-clause is also "*he*".
The subjects coincide.

---

[stackexchange.com](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/46329/82229):
**(2a)** *In daily speak, often "monkey" is used for apes, too, although technically not correct*. — correct
My variants:
**(2b)** *In daily speak, often "monkey" is used for apes, too, although **is** technically not correct*. — I don't know if it's correct
**(2c)** *In daily speak, often "monkey" is used for apes, too, although **it is** technically not correct*. — I think it's incorrect
**(2d)** *In daily speak, often "monkey" is used for apes, too, although **it is** technically not correct **to do so***. — I think it's correct

The subject of the main clause is "*monkey*".
The implying subject of the although-clause is "*it*".
The subjects don't coincide.

---

Could you tell me please which of my variants [(1c), (2b), (2c), (2d)] are correct and which are not?

Comment: In all of your "2" sentences, it should be "daily **speech**", because *speak* is not a noun.  Also, it would usually be phrased "...*monkey* is often used.."

Comment: 1) C) loud buzzer.  In everyday speech.

Answer (score 1):

1c it is not correct.

2b is incorrect, all the rest (2a, 2c, and 2d) are correct.

Comment: Do you consider "it" in (2c) as a dummy pronoun? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii  No, *it* is not a dummy pronoun there; it refers to *monkey*.  You can tell that it is not a dummy pronoun, because you could replace it with the word *monkey* and the sentence would still make sense.  A dummy *it* is like the one in "It is raining", where there is nothing that you could replace the *it* with.

Answer (score 1):

Your versions are not correct.

With few exceptions, English conjugated verbs require a subject. "Although" isn't an exception.

In the clauses, "Although is poor" and "although is technically not correct", the conjugated verb "is" doesn't have a subject, so the grammar is bad.

It's often possible to elide *both the subject and the conjugated verb*, as you did in "although poor" and "although technically correct", but not just the subject.

Comment: "as/than (is) + an adjective or past participle". For example "_as **is** possible_" from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/maximum_2): "_maximum - ​as large, fast, etc. as is possible_"

Comment: @Loviii Yes, with exceptions. "Although" is not an exception. I've adjusted my answer